# Построение графика на основе данных из массива php

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, диаграммы

- Добрый день, коллеги!
  Нужен совет, новичку. Есть массив из которого выходят данные через "return $dab".
- Таблица строится замечательно, а вот график не получается. Нужно вместо статичных данных, вытащить данные из массива через цикл. Нужен график за последние 5 дней по легковушкам и грузовикам. Как правильно отобразить данные из массива?

`

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Дата', 'Легковые', 'Грузовики', 'Всего'],

      /*  ['9.11.2016', 45, 34, 79],
          ['10.11.2016', 78, 47, 125],
          ['11.11.2016', 20, 40, 60],
          ['12.11.2016', 56, 74, 130],
          ['13.11.2016', 118, 122, 240],   */

      <?php foreach($dab as $dt){
        $i=0;
        $num=0;
      $dab = date('d.m.Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-$i, date('y')));?>

      <?php echo [$dab,  $dt['car'], $dt['truck'], $dt['all']]; ?>,

        <?php if($i>=5){ break;  }
        $i++;?>
     <?php } ?> 
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Статистика продажи машин за последние 5 дней',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

`<?php
   $data = [['Дата', 'Легковые', 'Грузовики', 'Всего'],[...],[...]];
   $dataJSON = json_encode($data)`

json_encode($arr) - преобразовывает массив в json

```
<script>
var data = JSON.parse('<?=$dataJOSN?>');
</script>
```

и все переменная готова

Comment: спасибо конечно! Вот только я не понял как переделать мой код согласно Вашим рекомендациям. И так попробовал и сяк. Ничего не получается путного. Можете объяснить на моем примере?!

Comment: @Aibek Sydygaliev Смотрите, сперва соберите просто в php массив данных какой вам нужен, затем при помощи функции `json_encode($data)` у вас создастся json строка, затем этот код вы можете поместить в переменную в js и уже ее подставить в `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data)`

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ:

1. Надо сделать

   - 2 функции.
   - а) Функция построения данных, в табличной форме (в этой таблице даты идут сверху вниз, начиная с той даты которая нужна по сегодня);
   - б) Функция № 2 построения данных, в табличной форме (для графика);
2. На нижнем примере рассмотрены данные за 5 дней (3 дня + 0 день + сегодня)

` function visits2($db){

```
    for($i=3; $i>=0; $i--){
        $later_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-$i, date('y'));
        $early_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-($i+1), date('y'));
        $db->where('date_reg',$early_date,'>');
        $db->where('date_reg',$later_date,'<');
        $visitors[$i] = $db->get('visitors2');

        $db->where('date_reg',$early_date,'>');
        $db->where('date_reg',$later_date,'<');
        $db->where('visit_type',1);
        $visitors2[$i] = $db->get('visitors2');

        $db->where('date_reg',$early_date,'>');
        $db->where('date_reg',$later_date,'<');
        $db->where('visit_type',0);
        $visitors3[$i] = $db->get('visitors2');

        $out[$i]['all']=count($visitors[$i]);
        $out[$i]['first']=count($visitors2[$i]);
        $out[$i]['order']=count($visitors3[$i]);


    } 

    $today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
    $db->where('date_reg',$today,'>');
    $out['today']['all']=count($db->get('visitors2'));  

    $db->where('visit_type',1);
    $db->where('date_reg',$today,'>');
    $out['today']['first']=count($db->get('visitors2'));

    $db->where('visit_type',0);
    $db->where('date_reg',$today,'>');
    $out['today']['order']=count($db->get('visitors2'));

    return $out;
}

$out2 = visits2($db);

// echo "<pre>"; print_r($out2); echo "</pre>"; die;
// echo $out[3];

function show_visit_chart($data,$num){
    $i=0;
    $g=-4;
    $num=$num-1;

    foreach($data as $dt){
        $date = date('d/m/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+($g++), date('y')));
        $pl=(int)$dt['all']-(int)$dt['first'];
        echo '["'.$date.'",'.$dt['first'].', '.$pl.'],';
        if($i>=$num){
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

function show_visit2($data,$num){
    $i=0;
    $g=-4;
    $num=$num-1;
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    echo '<thead class="thead-default"><tr><th>Дата</th><th>Первичные</th><th>По записи</th><th>Всего</th></tr></thead>';
    foreach($data as $dt){
        $date = date('d.m.Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+($g++), date('y')));
        echo '<tr><td>'.$date.'</td><td> '.$dt['first'].'</td><td> '.$dt['order'].'</td><td> '.$dt['all'].'</td></tr>';
        if($i>=$num){
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
}


    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['День', 'Первичные', 'По записи'],
          <?php show_visit_chart($out2,5);?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          // title: 'Статистика пациентов за последние 5 дней',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: {position: 'bottom'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>     

<section class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
          <h1><?php echo ""; ?></h1>

           <h3>График визитов</h3>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px; margin-left:-100px"></div>
</section> `
```

Не забудьте вставить еще подключение к
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">`

3. Надеюсь этот пример поможет другим новичкам! Удачи вам, коллеги! :-)